# How to handle large result sets with psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a query which gives about 14M rows (I was not aware of this). When I use psql to run the query, my Fedora machine froze. Also after the query was done, I could not use Fedora anymore and had to restart my machine. When I redirected standard output to a file, Fedora also froze.

So how should I handle large resultsets with psql?

Comment: Use a CURSOR and just check out the amount of rows your machine can handle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`psql` accumulates complete results in client memory by default. This behavior is usual for all `libpq` based Postgres applications or drivers. The solutions are cursors - then you are fetching only N rows from server. Cursors can be used by `psql` too. You can change it by setting `FETCH_COUNT` variable, then it will use cursors with batch retrieval size `FETCH_COUNT`.

```
postgres=# \set FETCH_COUNT 1000
postgres=# select * from generate_series(1,100000); -- big query
```

Comment: Now what does `explain` gives? The time to compute one fetch of rows or all the rows? I want to know how long postgres takes to compute all the rows.

Comment: @ericj: explain will be same in this case - although it can be different - cursors are optimized for fast start, but it is other case. The query processing is different. You can look to psql source code for implementation.